# Pycharm Import Error: No module named arcpy

Tags: python, pycharm, arcpy

I have followed previous instructions on how to use arcpy in Pycharm but it's still not working.  Here is what I've tried:

File > Close Project > Configure > Settings > Project Interpreter > "Gear" > Add > [image] > Apply > Ok > Open Project

But when I open my project and try to import arcpy and run my code, it says "ImportError: No module named arcpy".  I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: But have you installed the module?

Comment: Check that system path variable has set PYTHONPATH, if so remove it. restart Pycharm

Comment: You can use import sys; print ("\n".join(sys.path)) to check the default path or the system path Pycharm work with

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14713/setting-up-pycharm-to-reference-arcpy